# How to filter selective data from a postgres using PDI components?

Tags: regex, pentaho

For example : I have a column named description, in this column there are millions of records. I just want to filter records only with "a=x" (where x can be any value) using pentaho?.This pattern can be at any position in the column

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in your description column you always have a value after the pattern 'a=' you could just do the filtering in PostgreSQL using LIKE

```
SELECT
   description
FROM
   your_table
WHERE
   description LIKE '%a=%'
```

Then you just put this query inside a **Table Input** step in your transformation.